# Splitting the List

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

I want to split a list.
There is one set of list with two {x,{a,b}} elements.
it's like

```
list={① {{x1,{a1,b1}},{x2,{a2,b2}}},②{{x1,{a1,b1}},{x2,{a2,b2}}},③{{x1,{a1,b1}},{x2,{a2,b2}}}} (*and so on...*)
```

What function should I use to split the list when a1 and a2 are the same (a1=a2) and when they are different (a1≠a2)?

I created sample list below.

```
ListA={{{10, {1, 2}}, {10, {1, 2}}},{{2.5, {1, 2}, {17, {1, 1}}}, {{14, {2, 5}, {10, {1, 1}}},{{12.1, {1, 1},{3,{4,3}}}}
```

I want to split listA into lista and listb like this.

```
 lista(*a1=a2*)={{{10, {1, 2}}, {10, {1, 2}}},
        {{2.5, {1, 2}}, {17, {1, 1}}}}



listb(*a1≠a2*)={{{14, {2, 5}, {10, {1, 1}}},
       {{12.1, {1, 1}},{3,{4,3}}}}
```

Comment: The definition of `ListA` has unbalanced opening braces. Please use  lower case first letters for user-defined symbols.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited.

Comment: hare, your edit does not address Syed's comment -- `ListA` contains unmatched braces.

Answer (score 1):

```
ListA = 
  {{{10, {1, 2}}, {10, {1, 2}}}, 
   {{2.5, {1, 2}}, {17, {1, 1}}}, 
   {{14, {2, 5}}, {10, {1, 1}}}, 
   {{12.1, {1, 1}}, {3, {4, 3}}}};
GatherBy[ListA, Equal @@ Part[#, 1 ;; 2, 2, 1] &]
```

If you want the data to further show which case is which, maybe you want GroupBy rather than GatherBy:

```
GroupBy[ListA, Equal @@ Part[#, 1 ;; 2, 2, 1] &]
```

If you just want lista, then do this:

```
Select[ListA, Equal @@ Part[#, 1 ;; 2, 2, 1] &]
```

If you just want listb, then do this:

```
Select[ListA, Not[Equal @@ Part[#, 1 ;; 2, 2, 1]] &]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I carried out "GatherBy[ListA, Equal @@ Part[#, 1 ;; 2, 2, 1] &]".
Then, {{14, {2, 5}}, {10, {1, 1}}}and{{12.1, {1, 1}}, {3, {4, 3}} were also displayed.This means that  (a1=2,a2=1)and(a1=1,a2=4), so it's a1≠a2.

Comment: If possible please tell me what you mean by [#, 1 ;; 2, 2, 1] &]

Comment: I thought you wanted both lista and listb. The result my solution provides is {lista,listb}.

Comment: In my solutions, I've used GatherBy, GroupBy and Select. Each of these take a function as the second argument that performs the filtering. `Equal @@ Part[#, 1 ;; 2, 2, 1] &` is a function. I suggest you look at the documentation for Part and Apply and Function.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your kind explanation! It will be helpful